# How to exclude a record from the Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a drop down list 'Status' on my create view and it gets its data from the database meaning the data on the list are not hard coded but rather dynamic. Currently I have 3 records on the status table (i.e.Available, Unavailable and Cancelled). I want to **exclude the Cancelled** record so that on the drop down list I will only have Available and Unavailable. The cancelled status is still needed but used in a separate manner. Here are the codes

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int roomId)
        {
            var room = _db.Rooms.Single(r => r.Id == roomId);
            ViewBag.roomCode = room.RoomCode;
            var statList = _db.ReservationsStatus.ToList();
            var selectList = new SelectList((from s in statList.ToList()
                                             select new { statusId = s.Id, statusName = s.Name }), "statusId", "statusName");

            ViewData["sList"] = selectList;

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownList("ddStatus", (SelectList)ViewData["sList"])

        </div>
```

Any solutions will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var selectList = new SelectList((from s in statList.ToList() where s.Name != "Cancelled" select new { statusId = s.Id, statusName = s.Name }), "statusId", "statusName")
```

... assuming your Name property is a string and its value is Cancelled...

Comment: It worked! gonna go with this one, even if i increase the records on my status table, I will no longer need to change the codes. Tnx man

Answer (score 1):

var selectList = new SelectList((from s in statList.Where(x=>x.Name =="Available"||x.Name =="Unavailable")
                                             select new { statusId = s.Id, statusName =s.Name }), "statusId", "statusName");

u can also see the [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) method

Comment: Got it, tnx.. I knew I can use the where statement for this but I don't know the correct syntax of it in MVC (clearly still a newbie).

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to determine why "Cancelled" is different from the rest of the statuses. I would suggest adding a column to your database to indicate which of these statuses are shown in the UI.

The problem, as you described, is that with your database able to change at any time, you can't hard-code any particular status to include or exclude, because you may run into data integrity issues.

After adding the column (just a Boolean to the DB, I called it "userSelectable") you can exclude it in your LINQ select statement:

```
 var selectList = new SelectList((from s in statList.ToList()
                                  select new { statusId = s.Id, statusName = s.Name }
                                  where userSelectable = true), "statusId", "statusName");
```

Comment: The cancel record is the only thing that shouldn't show up on the drop down list even if we add the record on the Status table. And I forgot to mention that we have also a form when creating a status record, we don't input data directly from the DB. BUT, this logic helped me with another problem that I am currently having so tnx for that man.

Comment: @loulising If it's not appropriate to add the column to the Statuses, for business reasons, you could have an attached property table that has the Status Code (fkey) and Show in UI flag. It's just hard-coding that will always get you in trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the required status in the Linq statement through a where clause.